# How to create CGRect from CGMutablePath

Tags: macos, cgrect, cgpath

In order to use the `CGRect` intersection function I need to create a second `CGRect` from `CGMutablePath`. Is it possible?

```
let rect1 = CGRect(myPath) // not allowed
let intersectionRect = rect2.intersection(rect1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what rectangle you expect to get from the path, but do you perhaps want the `boundingBoxOfPath`?

```
let rect1 = myPath.boundingBoxOfPath
```